# Make different executables one library used by all

Tags: c, makefile

I have a project with the following structure:

```
- main1.c
- main2.c
- main3.c
- lib.h
- lib.c
```

All the `mains` use the import `lib`.

> How can I write a `Makefile` that creates 3 executables (one per each main)?

## First Approach

I created a Makefile that does that, but you'd need to append the name of the executable after calling the `make` command (i.e. `make main1`, `make main2`, etc), However if I try using only `make` (without arguments), it only makes the first main (`main1`).

```sh
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall
LDFLAGS=-framework OpenCL
DEPS=lib.h
OBJS=main1.o main2.o main3.o

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

main1: lib.o main1.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

main2: lib.o main2.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

main3: lib.o main3.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o main1 main2 main3
```

*Makefile*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html

> By default, the goal is the first target in the makefile (not counting
>   targets that start with a period). Therefore, makefiles are usually
>   written so that the first target is for compiling the entire program
>   or programs they describe.

So just add the below line as the first target in your makefile:

```
all: main1 main2 main3
```